# Tkinter Drag and Drop label info to a database

Tags: python, database, tkinter, drag-and-drop

I have created a simple GUI to see which seat a person is sat on.  The name labels can be drag and dropped onto different seat labels which re static.  Every time someone changes seat, the user can drap and drop the name label to a different seat.

I want to be able to sent that information to a database (it doesn't matter which, either excel or sql is fine), which I can then look at at a later stage and find out who sat where etc.  I have tried using the coordinates of the mouse, but its not accurate enough.  Is there a better way to do this?  Perhaps with widget.grid?

Thanks![enter image description here][1]

This is my code;

```
def label_maker(Seat_list,my_frame1, my_frame2):
    run_lisst_title_label1 = Label(my_frame1,text = "Seat",compound='center',bd=2,relief=SUNKEN,bg=title_label_bgcolour,fg="white",font = font,width=12)
    run_lisst_title_label1.place(x=7,y=50)
    y_loco=90
    x_loco=7

    for item in Seat_list[0:25]:
        run_label = Label(my_frame1,text = item,compound='center',bd=2,relief=SUNKEN,bg=seat_label_colour,fg="white",font = font,width=12)
        run_label.place(x=x_loco,y=y_loco)
        y_loco = y_loco + y_loco_plus
    
def drag_drop(name_list,my_frame2):

    consist_list_title_label1 = Label(my_frame2,text = "Name",compound='center',bd=2,relief=SUNKEN,bg=title_label_bgcolour,fg="white",font = font,width=12)
    consist_list_title_label1.place(x=7,y=50)


    def drag_start(event):
        widget = event.widget
        widget.startX = event.x
        widget.startY = event.y

    def drag_motion(event):
        widget = event.widget
        x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
        y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
        widget.place(x=x//5*5, y=y//5*5)

    y_loco=90
    for item in name_list[0:25]:
            x_loco=7
            lrv_label = Label(my_frame2,text = item,compound='center',bd=1,relief=SUNKEN,bg=lrv_colour,fg="white",font = font )
            lrv_label.place(x=x_loco,y=y_loco)
            lrv_label.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
            lrv_label.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag_motion)
            y_loco = y_loco +y_loco_plus

    y_loco=90

[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Is the user an administrator in charge of placing people or an end-user who chooses a seat?

Comment: An Administrator

Comment: It would be easier if it was the end-user. The end-user can interact only with a free seat or with his own seat. It would be possible to use a grid with text labels (static). And bind the callback function to specific labels (`label.bind("<Button-1>", callback_for_CRUD_magic)`).

Comment: I see you are using frames (`my_frame1`,  `my_frame2`?). When it comes to dnd, you can use canvas. Canvas has [many methods](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html) for getting and keeping track of the coordinates of objects placed in this widget.

Comment: Here is an example of [drag-and-drop code with canvas](https://github.com/GregOwen/DNDList/blob/master/dndlist.py). There, all the `self.elements` of the list are draggable text labels (DNDNode objects). 1) You can add static seat numbers, for example, using [`canvas.create_text`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_text.html). In `def makeCanvas(self)` I guess. 2) And find the name label dragged closest to the seat number using the `canvas.find_enclosed(x1, y1, x2, y2)`. All coordinates will need to be calculated in detail.

Comment: This can be tricky, as the user may simply not reach the desired seat or add multiple labels too close. You will need to save the state/coordinates of the canvas objects after `<ButtonRelease-1>` events.

Comment: As for the grid, you can have a look at the [`w.grid_location(x, y)`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid-methods.html) method.

Comment: Great thanks I will check a few of these methods out!